DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity) doesn't generate a value on insert for DateTime colums using SQL Server EF Core provider
When inserting new rows the NotifiedAt column with the [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] attribute doesn't get auto-populated.
The example from the official docs:
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public DateTime Inserted { get; set; }

What am I doing wrong?
Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#value-generated-on-add-1
Code:
[Index(nameof(OwnerId))]
[Index(nameof(UserPrincipalName))]
[Index(nameof(NotifiedAt))]
public class ApplicationNotification
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; init; }
    [Required] public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(256)] public string? DisplayName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(256)] public string? GivenName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(256)] public string? Surname { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(256)] public string? UserPrincipalName { get; set; }
    [Required] public string? Message { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime NotifiedAt { get; set; }
}

Error:
[2024-09-24T08:36:04.683Z] INSERT INTO [ApplicationNotifications] ([Id], [DisplayName], [GivenName], [Message], [OwnerId], [Surname], [UserPrincipalName])
[2024-09-24T08:36:04.683Z] OUTPUT INSERTED.[NotifiedAt]
[2024-09-24T08:36:04.683Z] VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6);
[2024-09-24T08:36:04.702Z] Failed to dispatch notification to owner e122277b-f274-4f61-b12d-d9dac9c0cea4 for 1 applications
[2024-09-24T08:36:04.702Z] An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'LEGO.IAM.AssetGovernance.DbContexts.AssetOwnershipContext'.
[2024-09-24T08:36:04.702Z] Result: Failed to dispatch notification to owner e122277b-f274-4f61-b12d-d9dac9c0cea4 for 1 applications
[2024-09-24T08:36:04.702Z] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
[2024-09-24T08:36:04.702Z] Exception: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
[2024-09-24T08:36:04.702Z]  ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'NotifiedAt', table 'AssetGovernance.dbo.ApplicationNotifications'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
[2024-09-24T08:36:04.702Z]  ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'NotifiedAt', table 'AssetGovernance.dbo.ApplicationNotifications'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.


They do mention that it is dependent on the provider and they do not mention specifically that it is supported with the SQL server provider. There is another section, which might imply that the SQL server provider does not support this automatically. See this: Creation timestamp However: I am not sure about it and if find the docs a bit confusing on the matter.

@Silvermind - Thank you. This might also mean that it's not supported for SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#creation-timestamp:~:text=However%2C%20specifying%20ValueGeneratedOnAdd%20on%20a%20DateTime%20property%20will%20have%20no%20effect%20(see%20the%20section%20below%20for%20DateTime%20value%20generation).

You might have to try that. I think it is dependent on the version of SQL Server. But as I found several answers about using GETDATE(), I think it was already supported as far back as SQL Server 2008.

Why not provide a default value of the column instead? If it's null, then insert the current time

That's what I meant and I think you can do this: modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationNotification>().Property(a => a.NotifiedAt).HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
